# How to properly iterate through an Object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out a proper way to loop through an Object while using TypeScript. The following examples would be valid JavaScript but I do understand why it becomes a problem in TypeScript, however I am not finding the correct way to proceed with this task and I was wondering if I am thinking wrong about it.

My goal is to iterate through a two-level-deep Object and be able to access the item directly from the Object at the end, and not only its value.

Example:

```
interface A {
  abc: number
  acd: number
}
interface B {
  bcd: number
  bde: number
}
interface C {
  cde: number
  cef: number
}
interface Data {
  a: A
  b: B
  c: C
}

const data: Data = {
  a: {
    abc: 1,
    acd: 2
  },
  b: {
    bcd: 3,
    bde: 4
  },
  c: {
    cde: 5,
    cef: 6
  }
}

// Trying with for-in
for (const cat in data) {
  for (const item in cat) {
    console.log(cat, item) // works just fine cause both are strings
    console.log(data[cat][item]) // both cat and items are strings and not keys of Data.
  }
}

// Trying with for-of
for (const cat of Object.keys(data)) {
  for (const item of Object.keys(cat)) {
    console.log(data[cat][item]) // Same, cat becomes just a string and not valid key of Data.
  }
}

// Trying with forEach
Object.keys(data).forEach((cat) => {
  Object.keys(cat).forEach(item => console.log(data[cat][item])) // same thing, cat is just a string and not exactly a key of Data
})
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: I don't think your code would work as intended even in plain JS...for example, your second `console.log` statement always outputs `undefined`. You probably wanted to do `for (const item in data[cat])`

Answer (score 2):

When you're iterating via `Object.keys(someObject)` - you're retrieving keys, not objects.

```
for (let catKey of Object.keys(data)) {
  for (let itemKey of Object.keys(data[catKey])) {
    console.log(catKey, itemKey)
    console.log(data[catKey][itemKey])
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and `for..in` also iterates keys.

Comment: @MattBrowne definitely

Answer (score 1):

I hate to use the "any" but in this code snippet i think its pretty safe to use duo to the if statments

```js
Object.keys(data).forEach((key1 ) => {
    if(key1 in data) {
        Object.keys((data as any)[key1]).forEach((key2) => {
            if(key2 in (data as any)[key1]) {
                console.log((data as any)[key1][key2])
            }

        })
    }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
for (let key of Object.keys(data.a)) {
   console.log(data.a[key]);
```

This will log out all the keys of `data.a`. You could do anything to each key by performing this loop through the keys and accessing those key values with `data.a[key]`.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.